# Hover effect fix

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I am using a hover effect in my portfolio website that acts funny when you go back and forth between boxes.  Any ideas how to fix it?

[my site](http://www.ideahoppers.com/#portfolio)

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
        jQuery(".website a").hover(function() {
            jQuery(".website a").not(this).animate({ opacity: 0.4}); 
        }, function() {
            jQuery(".website a").animate({opacity: 1});
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: The effect which you are trying to achieve can be easily achieved by css hover pseudo selector.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a simple fiddle to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like by applying jQuery's [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method does the trick. Below `stop(true, true)` method call is made before calling `animate` method. So currently running animations are stopped before new animations are made.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    jQuery(".website a").hover(function () {
        jQuery(".website a").not(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            opacity: 0.4
        });
    }, function () {
        jQuery(".website a").stop(true, true).animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    });

});
```

The first `true` parameter in the `stop(true, true)` method call is *A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well.* The second param is *A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately.* Both default to false.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/ydv5chmm/)